# Best way to detect if TextView's text has been changed?

Tags: android

Best way to detect if TextView's text has been changed?
Something similar to dirty check -- so I can only save the textfields that's changed.

Comment: Do you really mean text view changed? By default the `EditText` is supposed to change, the text view is supposed to be static.

Comment: No, I mean the string of the textview. I want to detect if the user edit the string text.

Answer (score 20):

add textChangeListener to text view as following.
write your stuff in  `onTextChanged()` method.

```
              TextView txtview = new TextView(this);
            txtview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```